# How to convert a .wav file to .m4a without adding any leading/trailing silence?

Tags: linux, macos, audio-conversion, m4a

The short question is: How do you convert a `.wav` file to `.m4a` without having any leading or trailing silence added to the output? The file is supposed to be played in an endless loop, where even a very short silence would be very well noticable.

For example:
One of the input (wav) files is 7.385 seconds long. When opening it in Audacity (Ubuntu) and saving it as .m4a, Audacity adds a total of 39 milliseconds of silence at the beginning (15) and at the end (24), which clearly breaks the audio loop.

Trying to convert the file in Garage Band (MacOS) can lead to better results: At best, only 15 milliseconds of silence is added at the end of the clip.

> Sidenote: To get Garage Band down to 15 milliseconds, the checkbox `Export cycle area, or length of selectged regions (if Cycle is turned off)` must be set. Beside that, `Track` and `Master` plugins have been disabled, as well as `Reverb` and `Echo`, which have also been disabled. But well, it's still 15 milliseconds too much...

So the question now is, how would you convert those files (on Linux or MacOS)?

You advise is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does your loop actually loop properly initially, at zero crossings, without clicks? What's going to loop it for playback? Most consumer stuff [ie things that are likely to use mp4] will add its own small delay on the loop anyway. If it's something you want for a ring-tone, you're better off looping it first, then saving out 39s of ready-looped sound.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the comment! Yes, the .wav file is looping perfectly. It's actually already used in an app. Problem is, the .wav file just takes too much space, hence the idea to convert it to m4a. Oh, and: Domo arigatou gozai masu!

Comment: OK. Sorry, I don't know of anything even vaguely 'pro' that deals in m4a at all to really be able to test this. Even the bargain-basement audacity up-converts on import. Doe tashimashite ;)) [& no, I don't speak Japanese, just used to work for a JP major music instrument company]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records, allow me to answer my own question:

This turned out to be a padding issue.
When converting from `wav` to `m4a`, the input data must be a multiple of 1024 samples. If it isn't, the output will be padded to the next multiple of 1024 samples, which causes the trailing silence.

For example: Imagine you want to create a 1 second .m4a file **without any trailing silence** from a wave file with a rate of 48.000Hz.
The first idea would be to simply cut the input data at sample 48.000, which should lead to a 1 second output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -b:a 128k -af atrim=end_sample=48000 output.m4a
```

Opening `output.m4a` in Audacity shows that the audio data has the expected length of 1.000 milliseconds, but the whole file length is 1.003 milliseconds, with a trailing silence of three milliseconds.

Now, if we cut the input file at the next closest multiple of 1024, instead of at 48.000 (which would be at sample 48.128):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -b:a 128k -af atrim=end_sample=48128 output.m4a
```

We'll end up with 1.003 milliseconds of audio content and file length, **and no silence added at the end of the audio data**.

So, to conclude all that: To create a loopable m4a file from a wav file, the number of samples of the input file must be a multiple of 1024 samples.

Guys, thank you for your help figuring this out!

What now remains is the question [how to stretch a wav file to a specific number of samples?](https://superuser.com/q/1769649/324820)

Answer (score 1):

Tetsujin's comment is a good one worth considering first. If you still want to convert audio formats, I'd use ffmpeg and give it this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.m4a
```

That'll take your input and copy the audio using aac `-c:a aac` at a bitrate of 256 `-b:a 256k` and wrap it in a m4a `output.m4a`

If you would like to loop your audio into a single file as Tetsujin suggested, add `-stream_loop n` where n is the number of loops -1, that you desire. and `-shortest`

This will give you a file with 4 loops.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 3 -i input.wav -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest output.m4a
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise! Unfortunately, `ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.m4a` also adds between 9 and 14 milliseconds of trailing silence, making me wonder, **could this be a padding requirement of the m4a format?** Looping the file would of course be a workaround, but considering that the input (wav) files are just a few MB, there would not be much gain in file size, while the loop would still not be perfect...

Comment: This is a surprisingly difficult task it seems. Still, +1 up for the detailed explanation! Thank you!

Comment: Padding it would save clicks on amateur edits. idk how the format work, though.. actually I just realised I really know surprisingly little about actual audio file formats, though I've been working with them just about since they were first invented … Monkey push buttons, move faders, out come audio mix. Monkey happy ;))

Comment: Check out atrim: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Comment: @Tetsujin ROFL :-D Thanks, I just spat my coffee all over my desk. Again :-D