# How to stretch a wav file to a specific number of samples?

Tags: audio, compression, audacity, wav

How do you convert the content of a wav file to a specific number of samples, but without adding any silence? I.e. how can you stretch the audio data to a certain number of samples?

**Some background information:**

This is contiuation of [How to convert a .wav file to .m4a without adding any leading/trailing silence?](https://superuser.com/questions/1769376/how-to-convert-a-wav-file-to-m4a-without-adding-any-leading-trailing-silence)

When converting a wav file to m4a, the m4a file will be padded to the next multiple of 1024 samples. Those padding samples will be silent. Now, if the audio file is meant to be played in an endless loop, those silent padding samples cause a short (but well audible) gap before the loop restarts at the beginning. The only way to avoid the gap is to ensure the number of samples of the input wav file is a multiple of 1024.

The audio is embedded in an app, and the app's file size should be as small as possible. Hence just stretching the audio over a few additional samples would be the preferred approach.

Hence the question, how can you stretch the content of a wav file to a certain number of samples? Ideally on Linux or MacOS.

Your advise is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To keep the relevant info available I edited the question to add your comment to @harrymc and link to the previous question. Did you test [atrim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) as suggested there?

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thank you very much for improving the question! Theoretically atrim would work to remove the number of samples the input data reaches past its last multiple of 1024 samples, but I'm afraid this could have some undesired side effects, like no longer looping perfectly. atrim could shorten the input data by up to 21 milliseconds (at 48kHz), which seems quite long, and I'm afraid it could theoretically also introduce some cracks when the loop restarts. So stretching the input appears to be the better option.

Comment: The original posting helped me to get a grasp of the situation :-) Never seen a situation where one would need to work on sample-accurate basis... but it actually looks like my long-time go-to tool might be the one for the job; [Ocenaudio](https://www.ocenaudio.com/). The timeline has an option to show samples, it has a decent stretch tool (at least decent enuff for this) and it can export MP4.

Answer (score 1):

One idea might be to concatenate multiple copies of the wav file to avoid
the long silence.

For example, if the last 1024 chunk has only 250 samples, concatenating
four of them will reduce the silent part to perhaps an unnoticeable
small segment.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. It would for sure work. Thing is, the audio is embedded in an app, and the app's file size should be as small as possible. Hence just stretching the audio over a few additional samples would be the preferred approach. That is, if it's even possible.... Still, +1 up for the idea!